# Call to undefined method DOMDocument::create_element()

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$node = $doc->create_element('markers');
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);
```

And for some reason I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method DOMDocument::create_element()
```

I'm testing it on localhost with Xampp and I can't make it work, any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: The methods are `createElement` and `appendChild` - camel case, not underscores

Comment: @iainn, you're right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> And for some reason I get the error:
>
> `Call to undefined method DOMDocument::create_element()`

The only reason you get this error is that the invoked method doesn't exist. Or it has a different name.

Have you read the documentation of [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)? I guess not.

The methods names are [`createElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and [`appendChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) and so on.